# How do I import certificate (.CER) in IIS

Tags: iis, windows-7, ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate

I have created certificates based on this tutorial:

http://ondrej.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/iis-7-and-client-certificates/

Then I have imported "MyPersonalCA.cer" on IIS host server based on this tutorial:

http://www.networksolutions.com/support/installation-of-an-ssl-on-certificate-microsoft-iis-7-x/

I had to import the certificate via MMC, because IIS is giving me an error:

"Cannot find the certificate request associated with this certificate file. A certificate request must be completed on the computer where it was created."

As stated this is a known bug, but i cant get pass the error.

I have imported certificate in Certificate (LocalComputer) snap in and provided a friendly name. It all looks ok.

But i still cant select the certificate on my webpage binding in IIS when trying to enable SSL.

EDIT

Ok I went as suggested and issued the .CER file via CertAuthority.
On another machine I have installed Windows Server and CA. I have created a request in IIS and issued myself a .CER file.
This file I can normaly import to Windows7 IIS.

But now I want to create client certificates.
The certificate is missing PVK file and i cant create client certificates as described in the first link.

Will post another question ...

System: Windows7 Home Premium SP1 32bit,IIS 7.5

Can someone point me to the right direction on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have to reissue your cert using a new CSR check out the following link. It is similar to the directions you have already followed but with a little more instruction to getting around this error.

http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-7.htm

Comment: Ok i get you, but i created the certificate via makecert.exe, because I do not have CA installed. Also the client certificates are created from this certificate as shown in my first link. Does that mean I will be able to re-create the cleint certificates with makecert.exe using this new certificate? Please enlighten a man wondering in the dark ...

Comment: This is just too weird.